# Was there any talk of adding a dispute settlement mechanism to the Regional Comprehensive Economic Partnership?

Tags: international, trade

> Yen Huai-shing, deputy director at the Chung-Hua Institution for
> Economic Research, wrote on Taipei Times that the RCEP is "not to have
> a strong impact" on Taiwan. She said that most observers did not
> expect the RCEP to provide a high degree of openness, and that it
> provides no dispute settlement mechanism when handling certain trade
> issues such as meat inspection regulations, adding, "In other words,
> they are more symbolic than binding."[27]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Comprehensive_Economic_Partnership

Was there any talk of adding a dispute settlement mechanism to the Regional Comprehensive Economic Partnership? Unlike some trade agreements, the Regional Comprehensive Economic Partnership doesn't yet feature a dispute settlement mechanism for handling certain trade issues, so I was wondering if there were any talk of adding one in the future, and wanted to know how such decisions are made within the RCEP and voted on.